# How do you create a KT1 address

Tags: kt1

How can I create a KT1 address?
The purpose of this address is that I can delegate to a baker.

Tutorials[1] I found have the command:
tezos-client originate account....
however, this returns an error and the tezos-client manual does not have any entry for originate account (it only has something for originate contract).

Thanks for your help

[1], the tutorials I am referring too are:
https://medium.com/cryptium/how-to-delegate-tezos-xtz-with-tezos-client-and-running-your-own-node-betanet-cea6960cf45
https://gspeagle.gitlab.io/tezosdocs/introduction/howtorun.html
https://blog.polychainlabs.com/tezos/2019/06/03/delegating-tezos.html

Answer (score 1):

The tutorials you are reading are woefully out of date. A KT1 for delegating has not been the requirement for almost 1.5 years. In protocol version 005, KT1s became only for smart-contracts. Any tz1/2/3 can delegate.

Comment: thank you very much, that explains it!